# Recreating the behavior of Haskell's `replicateM` in Scala

Tags: scala, monads, traits

I'm trying to learn how to do monadic code in Scala but I miss Haskell's ability to constrain types to belong to typeclasses declaring the type of a function.

For example, I'm trying to write something like `replicateM` from `Control.Monad` in Scala. Without caring about type annotations, this would be something like:

```
def replicateM(n: Int)(x: M[A]): M[List[A]] = n match {
  case 0 => map(x => List())
  case _ => for {
    head <- x
    tail <- replicateM(n-1)(x)
  } yield head: tail
}
```

(I see that this might not be the more efficient implementation, it's just a simple way to write it).

Where I stumble is: how do I properly annotate the types here? What type is M? How do I restrict M only to types that have `flatMap` defined on them? It feels like I could do this with traits but I'm not sure of how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think if you are looking for Haskell in Scala you definitely need to take a look at [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz). It already has replicateM, Monads, Monoids, Monad Transformers and much more

```
  import scalaz._
  import Scalaz._

  println(Option(1).replicateM(10))
```

Result

```
Some(List(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
```

Comment: Hum, that's nice to have. But I still want to try to implement this things myself so that I can understand Scala's type system better. I like to learn by implementing it myself. But it's nice to know that I can use scalaz in real code.

Comment: Further question: will Scalaz work on monads I define myself? I must extend some trait to declare a new monad?

Comment: Actually replicateM is a part of Applicative syntax, not Monad. You can take a look at scalaz source to get idea, how it's implemented. To create Monad for your custom type M[_] you need to have implicit scalaz.Monad[M] in scope, so yes, it's super easy to extend.